# Where can I find user culture if not in Thread.CurrentCilture

Tags: c#, locale, cultureinfo

Is it possible to find user's culture if I cannot use [Thread.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) nor (naturally) [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx)?
I cannot use them because I'm just modifying small part of the huge project, and `Thread.CurrentCulture` is set to different culture somewhere in it.
One possible solution is to remember original culture when `Thread.CurrentCulture` is being set. But it there a way to get proper user's culture no matter what?

Comment: "is set to different culture" - try to solve that, it's the real problem.

Comment: @Henk: yep, I know, that this is a sing of something not working as it should, but this part of the story is beyond my influence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can p/invoke [GetUserDefaultLCID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318135.aspx) and pass the resulting value to the [CultureInfo constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/205h6kwc.aspx) that takes an `int`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern int GetUserDefaultLCID();
```

---

```
CultureInfo defaultUserCulture = new CultureInfo(GetUserDefaultLCID());
```